# How to write multiple relation in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2, relational-database

i have in database one table, her data can be related with many tables, and i am using table below.
[image]

Columns:

- object - class name of the related model,
- object_id - her id,
- reason_id - id of the row in dictionary,
- comment - text decription

How to write this relation, using hasMany() and viaTable() methods ?

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are searching something like this: https://github.com/samdark/yii2-cookbook/blob/master/book/ar-single-table-inheritance.md